# Receiving data from a server using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm a beginner who started programming not long ago.    
I've just started using Java and Android studio and I'm stuck in the middle of a project that requires **sending and receiving data from an http server**. 
I've been told that Retrofit was the way to go, but I wasn't able to receive data (honestly, I don't know where to start).

However, I achieved sending data to the server (a string and an int) and this is the code I used.

I apologise for my mistakes and for being so inexperienced. Thanks in advance.

retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final TextView hora  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hora);
                    final int sharehora = Integer.valueOf(hora.getText().toString());
                    final TextView missatge  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                    final String shareMissatge = missatge.getText().toString();
                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://www.google.com/")
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();
                    CostumBody costumBody = new CostumBody();
                    costumBody.setMsg(shareMissatge);
                    costumBody.setTime(sharehora);
                    giapi service = retrofit.create(giapi.class);
                    service.Calltomyserver(costumBody);
    
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("error!", String.valueOf(ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

GIAPI

```
public interface giapi {
    @POST("/")
    Call<Void> Calltomyserver (@Body CostumBody user);
}
```

custumbody

```
public class CostumBody {
    public String msg;
    public int time;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to receive data - errors, timeout, crash, what's happening?  If there are any errors in logcat post them.

Answer (score 0):

well i use volley, honestly don't know why. but ill help anyway! installing volley is pretty simple just add

> compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

to your app gradle. So you want to retrieve data from database? and send data to database?

> step 1

**SETUP YOUR SERVER AND DATABASE**

make a php file to send whatever you want to the database.

> step 2

make the database convert to json. 
you can find a good tutorial [here!](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html)

> step 3

you need to parse json through your android project.
if you want to print it to list view, you can find a tutorial/example [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html)
if you just want to store the data, just take out the line were it is parsed to the list view!
...

**OKAY...**

to send data to the database, follow this video:

> How to Connect Android with PHP, MySQL - Best Android Studio Tutorial.

(youtube) ...

Hope this helped!